# On Google Forms, can someone edit their response but can't add a new one?

Tags: google-sheets, google-forms, google, google-apps-script-triggers

For example "someone 1" edits their response via the link that I have added in the Google Spreadsheet (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gtULaR5VEfuLOP4f73Z3KofsnksmpSid/view?usp=sharing), automatically he cannot add any more responses because I have enable "1 response restriction".

But when using different browsers or different computers, it can add responses, how to solve it? so that someone can only edit their responses without being able to add more responses?

Because the assumption is that the form has been closed, so one can only edit the responses that he has sent.

Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't.

It's not at all using about different browsers or computers, but about using different Google accounts. Your setting limits each account to one answer, but everyone can open as many accounts as they like. Given that Gmail is free, the required effort is minimal.